# SQlite: Select rows within a specific time range, ignoring the date

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called `messages` that stores messages from a chat with the following columns: `username, message, datetime`, where the type of datetime is TEXT and it is stored in the following format: "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss". I want to retrieve the average count of rows within a specific time range, without bothering with the date. For instance:

```
SELECT avg(count(message))
FROM messages
WHERE datetime < "2016/mm/dd 13:00:00" AND
      datetime > "2016/mm/dd 12:00:00"
```

Is there some operator that allows any character to take the place of "mm" and "dd". Essentially, I am trying to construct a query that retrieves the average amount of messages within a specific time range, not the amount of messages on a specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you want to use your `WHERE` clause to restrict to *any* calendar date in 2016 between `12` and `13` hours.  In this case, you can use [`STRFTIME`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to extract the year and hour in string format from your `datetime` column.

```
SELECT COUNT(message)
FROM messages
WHERE STRFTIME('%Y', datetime) = '2016' AND
      STRFTIME('%H', datetime) < '13' AND
      STRFTIME('%H', datetime) > '12'
```

Note that the reason while the inequalities should work with strings is because numerical strings still sort based on their lexigraphical order.

**Update:**

Since your datetime column is in a non standard format, you may be able to workaround this by substringing off the various pieces you need to use in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(message)
FROM messages
WHERE SUBSTR(datetime, 1, 4) = '2016' AND
      SUBSTR(datetime, 12, 2) < '13' AND
      SUBSTR(datetime, 12, 2) > '12'
```

Comment: It seems like sqlite only accepts datetimes formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS" with the hyphens separating the year, month and day, whereas my datetime strings are formatted with forward slashes.

Comment: @J.Doe Then you should convert your datetime to a proper format.  It will make your life much easier.  Without this, you would need some very ugly string manipulations to solve this problem.

Comment: Will I need to write a program that loops through each table entry and reformats the datetime string accordingly, or is there some way to this in one fell swoop with a single sqlite query? Furthermore, there is an an "aggregate" error when I attempt to use the AVG function. COUNT(message) only returns an integer representing the amount of entries that respect the WHERE clause, but an average calculation cannot be performed with only this information. The number of days needs to be known to in order to perform the average calculation.

Comment: @J.Doe I have given you an alternative query which just uses `SUBSTR` to extract the year and hour components.  With regard to your question about `COUNT` and `AVG`, it only makes sense to use one of them.